# Start Word without any popups

Tags: vb.net, office-interop

I am about to create a VB.NET Application that is able to automatically format Word documents or change specifical things in it. But the applications stops regularly working because Word (working in Background, not visible) opens popup Dialogs, e.g. if the document is a .odt file, or was downloaded from the internet, or even the "Save File" dialog.

Is there any possibilty to prevent Word from opening any of these dialogs?

I haven't found anything in the [MSDN Developer Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837519.aspx) concerning this subject either.

Does anybody have an idea how to do this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't done this with Microsoft Word, but I have done something similar in doing COM automation with Microsoft Project from .NET.  Below is the code fragment that turns off all sorts of annoying pop-ups from MS Project:

```
            mApp.DisplayAlerts = False

where mApp is Microsoft.Office.Interop.MSProject.Application
```

Comment: Thank you very much!

This works great!

In Word you can set an "alertLevel" with `.displayAlerts`, for example `AlertsAlll, AlertsMessageBox or AlertsNone`